# the &(*a) operation in c++, counter-intuitive?

Tags: c++

in this code:

```
  int* a;
  int* b;
  int c;
  int* d;
  a=new int(5);
  b=&(*a);
  c=*a;
  d=&c;
  cout<<"*a = "<<*a<<endl;
  cout<<"a = "<<a<<endl;
  cout<<"b ="<<b<<endl;
  cout<<"d = "<<d<<endl;
```

I get:

```
*a = 5
 a = 0x83a2008
 b =0x83a2008
 d = 0xbfbfe540
```

why is d different from b? Aren't they both &(*a) ? how can I get the d result with a single line?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The value of `c` is the value of `a`, but not the address of `a`.  When you do `d = &c`, you've gotten the address of `c`.

Comment: `d` points at `c`. What makes you think `c` is stored at the same place as `*a`?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling homework tag is depricated .

Comment: @phoxis Thanks for the info; Any replacement?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: No. [There's no need to distinguish questions as homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` points to a dynamically allocated location, holding the value 5. When you do `c = *a;`, you're copying the *value* 5 from that dynamically allocated location into `c`. You're then taking the address of `c` and assigning it to `d` (and printing it out).

When you end up with is something like this:

[image]

The solid lines indicate a pointer referring to a location. The dashed line indicates movement of data.

Answer (score 6):

`c` is its own `int` and not an `int*`. When you say `c = *a`, you're actually assigning the value pointed to by `a` to a separate integer with its own space in memory (even though this `int` is not an `int*`, it still has to exist somewhere in memory).

So when you say `d = &c`, you're getting the address of `c`, not the value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
d = &c;
```

`d` points to the storage location designated by `c`, which is not the storage location pointed to by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

d is the address of c which is a local stack variable. b is the address of the integer you allocated on the heap and stored the address of in a.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is new instance of integer that's why `d` is not equal `a` nor `b`. So when You try to get address of value stored in `a` you get exactly address of `a`. But when you first assign value of `a` to `c` and then print address of `c` you get different address than `a`. In C++ you operate on real objects not references like in Java or C#. when you  assign value to variable you copy every filed stored in this variable, but be careful - by default `=` operator don't do deep cloning.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something in C11/C99 Section 6.5.3.2 Paragraph 4 and footnote 102

> a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand. The
>   unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. **If the operand
>   has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’**. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the
>   unary * operator is undefined.102)

And footnote 102 tells

> 102) **Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and
>   &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2))**. It always true that if E is a function
>   designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary operator,
>   *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E. If *P is an lvalue and T is the name of an object pointer type, *(T)P is an lvalue
>   that has a type compatible with that to which T points. Among the
>   invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are
>   a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of
>   object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its
>   lifetime. is &

**EDIT**
`c = *a;` will result in an undefined behaviour, as the memory location 5 is not allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the rules and subtleties that go into this, but the compiler is able to simplify `&(*a)` to just be `a`.  So you are initializing `b` to point at the same integer that `a` points at (`b = a`).  Then you are copying the integer by value to `c`.  Then you are initializing `d` to point at `c`.  So `a` and `b` point to the same integer, but `d` points to something else.